# React Native: O componente não encontra dados de um state após um setState

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, axios, react-hooks

Estou com esse problema à semanas:
estou usando React Hooks para fazer uma requisição a uma api interna usando o **useEffect** para fazer uma requisição e depois armazenar o resultado dento de um **setState**. Se dou um console.log o primeiro resultado e *array [ ]* (vazio) e depois um array com as informações esperadas, quando tento renderizar dentro de uma`<Text>{user.name}</Text>` dá o erro abaixo.

> TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'user.name')

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([])
...
useEffect(() => {
 async function loadUser(){
   const response = await api.get('/user/painel', {
   headers: {user_id}})
   setUser(response.data)
 }
 loadUser();
}, [ ])
...
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>{user.name}</Text>
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem, mas pq vc joga isso em um array se é um unico objeto ?
Se forem diversos objetos em um array, não tem como pegar usando 
`user.name`
Se for um unico objeto retornando,vc nao precisa declarar esse estado como array.
Se for um unico objeto, tenta assim para ver se vai:
`{ user && user.name }`

Comment: Era isso mesmo, a função retorna um array e dentro um objeto. Eu Estava pegando direto no objeto, por isso que me não conseguia renderizar o {user.name}.
A solução foi fazer um user.map() pra renderizar, mas como se trata de React Native usei o <FlatList>.
Obrigado!!!

Comment: Se vc tiver o ID desse usuario, vc tbm pode usar o metodo Array.find( )  para encontrar esse usuario dentro do vetor. Ai depois vc pode usar ele com   {  user.name  }.

Answer (score 1):

Ocorre esse erro por conta que está utilizando uma requisição assíncrona, para funcionar corretamente tente separar a função fora do hooks, assim deve funcionar, é para ler o Array retornado, percorre usando a função map.

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState([])
...

async function loadUser(){
  const response = await api.get('/user/painel', 
  {
     headers: {user_id}})
     setUser(response.data)
  }
}
 
useEffect(() => {
  loadUser();
}, []);

...
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {
      user.map(
      Name => {
        return (<Text>Name</Text>);
        }
      )
    }
  </View>
)
```